# How to close debug window (qt client on linux)

Tags: litecoin, dogecoin, litecoin-qt

I have the same problem with the Litecoin and Dogecoin client. Once I open the window in the menu `Help > Debug window` there is no way of closing it (no X in the corner of the window).

I'm using Debian and Gnome 3.

The following image contains the Dogecoin client (downloaded from Github and compiled), Litecoin client looks just the same.

[image: Dogecoin client with debug window open]

Comment: I checked in Bitcoin-Qt on Ubuntu and it had an exit button in the corner. It might be a bug.

Comment: Can confirm as well on Ubuntu. Could you post a screenshot of the client with debug window open?

Comment: @Tony I added a screenshot.

Comment: If you right-click on the top bar, does that help?

Comment: @Tony YES, thanks a lot. Right-clicking on the title (or pressing ALT+SPACE) bar brings up the window's menu where Close is one of the options. Also the menu actually shows the well-known hotkey (ALT+F4) to close the window. These things should have been familiar from the windows world... - Please also post your suggestion as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right-click on the top bar, and it will bring up a menu that allows you to close it.